# Find maximas and minima of time series values using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a certain set of index values that increase and decrease over time . I wish to identify the time periods during which values rise and values fall. The data looks like this:

[image]

I tried partitioning the values by the range and I definitely don't think I'm doing it right. Here's the query I wrote which at best is giving me ordered dates

```
SELECT
  date,
  MAX(index) OVER (PARTITION BY MAX(CAST(index AS numeric))
  ORDER BY
    date)
FROM (
  SELECT
    (value1 - value2) AS index,
    date
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table` )
GROUP BY
  date,
  index
ORDER BY
  date
```

My ultimate goes is that I want to implement a query that results in something like this when asked for minima values and likewise for maximas

```
Row |    date    |       minimas
-------------------------------------
1   | 2017-02-04 | 0.3149100257069409
2   | 2017-12-05 | 0.5784622847441183
```

Comment: What if two values are the same in a row?

Comment: In that case, both would have different dates and I would need both the dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling adjacent duplicate values is tricky.  You don't specify how you want these handled.  If you only want the first such value, then filtering works:

For local minima:

```
SELECT Row, date, f0 AS minimal
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(f0) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as f0_lead
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   LAG(f0) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS f0_lag
            FROM `project.dataset.table` t
           ) t
      WHERE f0_lag IS NULL or f0_lag <> f0
     ) t
WHERE (f0 < f0_lag or f0_lag is null) and
      (f0 < f0_lead or f0_lead is null);
```

Or, if you like, you can simplify the comparisons:

```
SELECT Row, date, f0 AS minimal
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(f0) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as f0_lead
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   LAG(f0) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS f0_lag
            FROM t
           ) t
      WHERE f0_lag IS NULL or f0 < f0_lag
     ) t
WHERE f0 < f0_lead or f0_lead is null;
```

Local maxima can follow the same logic with the `<`s changed to `>`s.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=53627142028a59a4f577bee1f380fe80) is a db<>fiddle (which uses Postgres, but that doesn't matter).

EDIT:

Returning all the minima/maxima in a row is more challenging.  The following works in BigQuery:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 1 AS Row, '2017-01-19' AS date, 0.3904 AS f0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,  '2017-02-04', 0.3149 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2.5,  '2017-02-05', 0.3149 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,  '2017-03-24', 0.3302 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,  '2017-04-09', 0.5339 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,  '2017-05-11', 0.7753 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,  '2017-05-27', 0.8539 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,  '2017-09-16', 0.8803 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7.5,  '2017-09-17', 0.8803 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7.7,  '2017-09-18', 0.8803 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,  '2017-10-02', 0.8570 UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,  '2017-11-03', 0.7744 UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, '2017-11-19', 0.6092 UNION ALL
    SELECT 11, '2017-12-05', 0.5785
)
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MAX(f0_lag) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) as grp_f0_lag,
             MAX(f0_lead) OVER (PARTITION BY grp) as grp_f0_lead
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   COUNTIF(f0_lag <> f0) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as grp,
                   LEAD(f0) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as f0_lead
            FROM (SELECT t.*,
                         LAG(f0) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS f0_lag
                  FROM t
                 ) t
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE (f0 < grp_f0_lag or grp_f0_lag is null) and
      (f0 < grp_f0_lead or grp_f0_lead is null) ;
```

Basically, this is identifies groups of adjacent values.  It then spreads the maximum `lag()` and `lead()` values through the group (for the maximum, you want to spread the minimum values).

The entire group is then treated as a unit and in the result set.

Comment: Thanks! This gives what I need. As per duplicate values in adjacent rows, the dataset is such that it's highly unlikely that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * EXCEPT(prev, next), 
  CASE 
    WHEN prev < next THEN 'min'
    WHEN prev > next THEN 'max'
    WHEN prev IS NULL THEN 'start'
    WHEN next IS NULL THEN 'finish'
  END extremum
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    SIGN(index - LAG(index) OVER(ORDER BY DAY)) prev, 
    SIGN(LEAD(index) OVER(ORDER BY DAY) - index) next
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE IFNULL(prev != next, TRUE)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2017-01-19' day, 0.39 index UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-02-04', 0.31 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-03-24', 0.33 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-04-09', 0.53 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-05-11', 0.77 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-05-27', 0.85 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-09-16', 0.88 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-10-02', 0.85 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-11-03', 0.77 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-11-19', 0.61 UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-12-05', 0.57 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(prev, next), 
  CASE 
    WHEN prev < next THEN 'min'
    WHEN prev > next THEN 'max'
    WHEN prev IS NULL THEN 'start'
    WHEN next IS NULL THEN 'finish'
  END extremum
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
    SIGN(index - LAG(index) OVER(ORDER BY DAY)) prev, 
    SIGN(LEAD(index) OVER(ORDER BY DAY) - index) next
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
WHERE IFNULL(prev != next, TRUE)
-- ORDER BY day
```

with result

```
Row day         index   extremum     
1   2017-01-19  0.39    start    
2   2017-02-04  0.31    min  
3   2017-09-16  0.88    max  
4   2017-12-05  0.57    finish
```

Answer (score 0):

We can define a local minimum as being a point on an x axis of time where the response value both before and after is greater than the value at the minimum point.  In the case of an endpoint on either end, then only one value would need to be greater.  We can try using the `LEAD` and `LAG` functions here:

```
SELECT Row, date, f0 AS minimal
FROM
(
    SELECT Row, date, f0,
        LAG(f0, 1, f0 + 0.1) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS f0_lag,
        LEAD(f0, 1, f0 + 0.1) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS f0_lead
    FROM project.dataset.table
) t
WHERE f0 < f0_lag AND f0 < f0_lead;
```

Here is a [demo in SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a58c1de761479f4842fe2b7a1bf42804) using your sample data.  As I based my answer off SQL Server, as I don't have access to BigQuery, you may have to slightly tweak the syntax I used.